# login page error in php

Tags: javascript, php

i m creating login page in php, but some error in it. when i enter wrong username or password then blank window is coming error messages are not and when both fields are empty then error messages are show.

this is login page code

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('ganga_hms') or die(mysql_error());
   
 $login_type=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_type']);
 $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
 
  if($username!=''&&$password!='')
  {

  $query="SELECT username, password, account_type FROM login WHERE username='$username'and password='$password' and account_type='$login_type'";
  $sql=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $rows=mysql_num_rows($sql)or die(mysql_error());
  
  if($rows==1)
  {
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[0];
   $_SESSION['username']=$username;
   $_SESSION['login_type']=$login_type;
   header('location:first_index.php');
    
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Plz enter correct username or password');</script>";
    header('location:index.php');
  } 
  }
  else
 {
  
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('enter username or password');</script>";
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>"; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` (use `PDO` instead). Kill script after sending new location in `header`. And of course show us some more code.

Comment: What is the second else for?

Comment: Oh, and you are sending HTML to the browser and then trying to send new header. It'll definitely fail :)

Comment: After fixing any errors, please change that "plz" to "please"...

Comment: As Elon says, your `echo` will ensure the `header()` gets ignored - at this point PHP has sent all the headers it has in order to send content, and no more headers can be sent. Remove the `echo` and use this instead: `header('Location: /index.php?fail=1')`. You can then detect that on the page and show a failure message.

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra "}" in else condition:try below code

```
$sql=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows=mysql_num_rows($sql)or die(mysql_error());

if($rows==1)
{
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[0];
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $_SESSION['login_type']=$login_type;
    header('location:first_index.php');

}
 elseif($rows!=1)
{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Plz enter correct username or password');</script>";
        header('location:index.php');
}   
else
{

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('enter username or password');   </script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";   
 }
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. He just skipped some of his code.

Comment: I think that he just tried to check if his returned string was empty.. He just forgot to paste it

Answer (score 0):

add session start at top

```
session_start();
```